# Embedded web browser in kivy | Error with android.config

Tags: python, android, kivy, apk

I am writing an application on python with kivy. And use this example: https://github.com/kivy/kivy/wiki/Android-native-embedded-browser

I am going to create apk. What should be in requirements, permissions in my spec file of buildozer?

When I run this program in PyDroid3, I had this error:

> [ INFO ] [Logger ] Record log in /storage/emulated/0/Download/.kivy/logs/kivy_20-01-01_4.txt
>
> [INFO ] [Kivy ] v1.11.0.dev0, git-8b6af30, 20190320
>
> [INFO ] [Python ] v3.7.2 (default, Mar 20 2019, 15:02:54)
>
> [GCC 8.2.0]
>
> [INFO ] [Factory ] 184 symbols loaded
>
> [INFO ] [Image ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_gif (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
>
> Traceback (most recent call last): File "/storage/emulated/0/Download/t.py", line 6, in from android.runnable import run_on_ui_thread
>
> File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.7/site-packages/android/runnable.py", line 8, in from android.config import JAVA_NAMESPACE
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'android.config'

Comment: Does the android module exist on the device?

Comment: Yes, of course. Because, string "from android.runnable import run_on_ui_thread" does not give an error.